# Query with GroupJoin method can not be translated

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I am traing to get identity users with roles  using GroupJoin

I am getting this exception
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet()

> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .GroupJoin(
> inner: DbSet<IdentityUserRole>()
> .Join(
> inner: DbSet(),
> outerKeySelector: ur => ur.RoleId,
> innerKeySelector: r => r.Id,
> resultSelector: (userRole, role) => new {
> userRole = userRole,
> role = role
> }),
> outerKeySelector: u => u.Id,
> innerKeySelector: urGroup => urGroup.userRole.UserId,
> resultSelector: (u, roleGroup) => new {
> u = u,
> roleGroup = roleGroup
> })' could not be translated.

The code that generate exeption is  :

```
var users = _userManeger.Users
                    .GroupJoin(
                        _context.UserRoles
                        .Join(_roleManager.Roles,
                             ur => ur.RoleId, r => r.Id,
                             (userRole, role) => new { userRole, role }),
                        u => u.Id, urGroup => urGroup.userRole.UserId,
                        (u, roleGroup) => new { u, roleGroup })
                    .Select(urg => new SearchResponseDTO
                    {
                        UserName = urg.u.UserName,
                        Email = urg.u.Email,
                        PhoneNumber = urg.u.PhoneNumber,
                        FirstName = urg.u.FirstName,
                        LastName = urg.u.LastName,
                        Roles = urg.roleGroup.Select(c => c.role.Name).ToList()
                    });
        var list = users.ToList();
```

Can someone help me with this

Comment: I tried it it dint helped or did not undestand how to aply it

Comment: @VaqifQurbanov Instead of `GroupJoin`, use correlated sub query. And better define and use navigations properties, thus eliminate the need of joins (group or regular) at all.

Comment: Show your model, I will help to rewrite query.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev It is not my models it is asp.net core identity models . Should i configure it with fluent api ?

Comment: I see. Yeah, [adding navigation properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-6.0#add-navigation-properties) is unfortunately not easy to do, even though once done, it's the easiest way to query the data in EF Core. Try correlated query then, I've shown that the linked post by Svyatoslav, you'd basically need to familiarize with LINQ *query syntax*, which for joins is much easier than the method syntax you are using in the example. Of course the same can be done with method syntax, but not so easy to explain.

Comment: @IvanStoev ye thanks it worked with sub quarry but why it didnt worked with GroupJoin ?

Comment: @VaqifQurbanov As I explained in the linked post (and links inside), EF Core team is not willing to add translation for LINQ `GroupJoin` construct, that's why. It is perfectly possible, just they don't want to do it (they don't see a value for doing it since you have the aforementioned "workaround").